# Can a react component return image data so that the url mapped to that component (react-router-dom) can be used as img src=url

Tags: reactjs

I have an app with authentication. I'm using 'react-draft-wysiwyg' to allow the user to create content. The image action in 'react-draft-wysiwyg' prompts for a url and generates a standard img tag with the src=url.

The user can upload image data and I'm trying to produce a component to fetch and provide the image data where the url to that component can be used as img src. Here is my current component stripped to the bare minimum.

```
import {useLocation, useParams} from 'react-router-dom';
import {getDocumentByPath} from '../../helpers/service';

export default () => {
  const location = useLocation();
  const {affiliationId} = useParams();
  const params = new URLSearchParams(location.search);
  const path = params.get('path');

  getDocumentByPath(affiliationId, path).then(data => {
    window.location = URL.createObjectURL(data);
  });
  return null;
};
```

The service makes a request with authentication to get the file data. If I hit the url mapped to this component with the browser it displays an image in the browser window. If used as image src it just displays a broken link.

Comment: You question is not that clear, can you provide a code example?

Comment: where are you using that `<img src={src} />` in your code? Also I just realized in your title you have typed `<img src='{src}' />` which might be the reason why it does not work

Comment: sorry, `<img src={src} />` was just an example. Edited to clarify (hopefully).

Comment: I have discovered that my solution will work as an 'embedded' url but not 'image' url in 'react-draft-wysiwyg'